# How to Call Stripe Checkout from a rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm using the stripe checkout api with a rails app. I want to redirect to the checkout page when a user submits a form. The issue I'm running into is that Stripe checkout requires a button to be clicked which will trigger a javascript function, that takes the session id and redirects to the checkout page.

My problem is that when the user submits the form I want to use their submitted email to create the checkout session and link their stripe customer account to their checkout. So on the form submit I am able to create the session fine, I'm just not able to also trigger the frontend javascript function once the session has been created.

I've tried to call a javascript function directly from the rails controller and pass it the session id, I was not able to get this working but feel it's likely close to the solution. How specifically can I trigger the javascript function once the controller has created the session

This is the Javascript function I want to call in my controller

```js
function go_to_stripe(sessionId) {
  var stripe = Stripe("<%=ENV["STRIPE_PUB_KEY"]%>");

  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId: sessionId
  }).then(function (result) {
    console.log("hitting the then with result of ", result);
  });
}
```

I've tried this in the controller (and a few variations of it) but it doesn't call the javascript function.

```rb
# this returns the session id 
@stripe_session_id = create_stripe_session(@cart)
respond_to do |format|
   format.html 
   format.js { render :js => "go_to_stripe("+@stripe_session_id+");" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

found a fix based on https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3697-server-generated-javascript-responses

The key was having remote: true on the form as well as naming the javascript file the same as the controller action. change the javascript in the file to contain the body of the function.

javascript

```
var stripe = Stripe("<%=ENV["STRIPE_PUB_KEY"]%>");

stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  sessionId: "<%= @stripe_session_id %>"
}).then(function (result) {
  console.log("hitting the then with result of ", result);
});
```

rails controller

```rb
@stripe_session_id = create_stripe_session(@cart)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a tutorial](https://dev.to/nicolrx/how-to-use-stripe-checkout-from-a-rails-controller-without-javascript-106i) to redirect to Stripe Checkout from a Rails controller. The idea is to create the Stripe Session after a User is registered (using Devise), within `the after_sign_up_path_for` method:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    super(resource)

        Stripe.api_key = "#{ENV['STRIPE_API_KEY']}"

        # See https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create
        # for additional parameters to pass.
        # {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} is a string literal; do not change it!
        # the actual Session ID is returned in the query parameter when your customer
        # is redirected to the success page.
        session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
            success_url: "success_url",
            cancel_url: "cancel_url",
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            mode: 'payment',
            line_items: [{
                # For metered billing, do not pass quantity
                quantity: 1,
                price: ENV['STRIPE_PRICE_ID']
            }],
            locale: "fr",
            customer_email: current_user.email
        )

        return session.url

  end
```

Doing so, the user is automatically redirected to Checkout.